# Copy Paste all rows except header if condition met

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, the first one is for database all products and the second for a specific product, I want to copy the data from database to the product table based on the name of product.

I wrote this code but got an error message on product name

> "Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Can you please review and edit my code please? I'm really appreciate it.

```
Sub Amigos_Reza()        
    Dim productname As String
    Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long

    'clear old data from product table
    ShBF.Rows("6:" & ShBF.Rows.Count).ClearContents

    finalrow = ShPDE.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    > productname = ShPDE.Range(i, 6).Value ' I tried to change i by the number of rows for example "5" and still got the same error message

    For i = 5 To finalrow
        If productname = "Amigoz" & "Reza" Then
            ShPDE.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 10)).Copy
            ShBF.Cells(6, 3).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i

    With ShBF
        .Select
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

What should I do to change my variable in order to my code works?

Comment: Where does your error happens? Edit your question and tell us the exact line where this error happens please.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because in this line `productname = ShPDE.Range(i, 6).Value` your `i` is `0` but a row `0` does not exist because row counting starts with `1`.

`i` is not defined outside your `For` loop.

---

Note that `"Amigoz" & "Reza"` is the same as `"AmigozReza"` So you probably meant something like

```
If productname = "Amigoz"  Or productname = "Reza" Then
```

Also note that you paste always into the exact same cell `ShBF.Cells(6, 3).PasteSpecial` so if your loop finds multiple product names then you will overwrite your destination.

Comment: Thanks for your solution the product name is "Amigos Reza" can I write it "Amigos Reza" instead of "Amigoz" & "Reza", do I need to concatenate the 2 words or not?